# Executing PS Script within a Start-Job Scriptblock on W2K3 Fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute the scriptblock below.  This works fine on Win 7 but never succeeds on W2K3.  Job stays in a perpetual running state.  Any idea why?

```
$Scriptblock = {
    Add-Content c:\temp\test.txt -Value "Starting..."
    $processes = c:\temp\test.ps1
    Add-Content c:\temp\test.txt -Value $processes
    Add-Content c:\temp\test.txt -Value "finished"
}

If (-not(Test-Path "c:\temp\test.ps1"))
{
    Add-Content c:\temp\test.ps1 -Value "get-process"
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock
```

Comment: You can execute `Receive-Job` before the job is done to get back intermediate output and errors.  What output (if any) do you get from Receive-Job while the job is running (and not completing)?